# If a function is executed inside another function, would it immediatly qualify as a callback func?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, functional-programming

I been reading some definitions about callbacks, and on FCC, it states that:

> "Callbacks are the functions that are slipped or passed into another
>   function to decide the invocation of that function."

Now, this created some confusion because on the following `prepareTea()` would qualify as a callback:

```
const prepareTea = () => 'greenTea';

const getTea = (numOfCups) => {
  const teaCups = [];

  for (let cups = 1; cups <= numOfCups; cups += 1) {
    const teaCup = prepareTea();
    teaCups.push(teaCup);
  }

  return teaCups;
};
```

But as far as I read, to be a callback, it needs to be passed in as arg.

Could you clarify?

Thank you

Comment: This is just taking closure over `prepareTea` function. Not *"passed into"* `getTea`

Comment: @Tiago as far as I understand it, yes, a callback function is a function that is passed in as an argument. Just calling a function inside another function isn't inherently a `callback`

Comment: Well, I knew that, but then I read this it made me think...

Comment: I don't know what source you're reading, but they key part of that quote is "slipped or passed". I'm not sure what "slipped" might mean but hard-coding that function directly into the `getTea()` function doesn't seem like "slipped" or "passed".

Comment: `const teaCup = prepareTea();` is not a callback, that is just a normal function call. callback is typically dealing with asynchronous tasks and you pass the function to be called to that asynchronous task. Your code is not passing in a function to be called and it is not being called after some task has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A callback is a function that is passed into another function as an
>   argument to be executed later.

When you take a look at [the ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19), you will see that parameter names are `callbackFn` which expecting a function as an argument.

Your code is not using any callback functions but we can convert it together to make it use.

```
const prepareTea = () => 'greenTea';

const getTea = (numOfCups, callbackFn) => { 
  const teaCups = [];

  for (let cups = 1; cups <= numOfCups; cups += 1) {
    const teaCup = prepareTea();
    teaCups.push(teaCup);
  }

  console.log('Created cups');
  callbackFn(teaCups);
};

const callbackFunction = cups => {
  console.log('Number of cups', cups.length);
}

getTea(4, callbackFunction); // Pass callbackFunction as an argument to getTea
```

We have used `callbackFunction` as a callback. We defined it as a regular function but used it as a callback. So this means we can use any function as a callback.

---

Why `prepareTea` is not used as a callback?

Because you used its return value directly. If your `prepareTea` function is defined like below:

```
const prepareTea = cb => cb('greenTea');
```

And you use this function as:

```
prepareTea(tea => teaCups.push(tea));
```

Then you can say that you used the `prepareTea` function as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

The term callback is a bit blurry. Let's look at two related terms with more precise semantics:

*Higher Order Function*

A HOF takes at least one function argument. In Javascript the term is also used for functions that return another function, but this is uncommon.

*Continuation*

A continuation in a language without continuations on a language level is always encoded by continuation passing style. A CPS function takes a continuation `k` as its last argument and calls `k` with its result value, i.e. a CPS function doesn't return a result but passes it to its continuation.

**Conclusion**

A callback function is clearly an higher order function. It is also a CPS function but without the constraint that it has to take the continuation as its last argument.

Comment: "A callback function is clearly an higher order function." This sentence is confusing: which one of the two functions is the callback then? The one that accepts the function being passed in or the one that is passed in?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I confused it. The function that is passed as an argument is the callback function. In my opinion it is unecessary to assign a special term to such a function. It is just a function and it totally depends on the higher order function whether it is invoked at all, once, twice or any number of times. Passing a function argument is like passing a lazily evaluated expression, that is there is no difference between a function and normal data except that a function is evaluated only when needed.

Comment: Thanks bob for the input!